# Good training on shrinking / growing files on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, configuration, best-practices

I am looking for basic file shrinking / growing training for SQL Server.  I see a number of similar questions as I post this - will read those answers now

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

There's not much to know.

File Growth and Shrinking operations are intensive and should be done as little as reasonably possible, to minimize any contention on the database from them.

Typically you want to pre-size your database to a reasonable size at initial creation. Some people even pre-size it to the entire size of remaining free space on the disk it lives on, and monitor the space consumption internally to know when they'll eventually need to add more disk space. This reduces the chances of any growth operations until then. I prefer this methodology, when possible.

You should set the autogrowth setting to a fixed amount instead of a percentage, that way as the file gets bigger, growing doesn't take longer and longer and get out of control with the amount of space it grabs, with each growth operation.

Also, [instant file initialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-instant-file-initialization?view=sql-server-ver16) is a useful feature to be aware of. It improves performance of Growth operations for data files by not having to zero out reclaimed bytes as new data is written. Instead it just directly overwrites the deleted data with the new data. Less I/O operations results in some performance improvement with this.

From the docs:

> By default, data and log files are initialized to overwrite any existing data left on the disk from previously deleted files. Data and log files are first initialized by zeroing the files (filling with zeros) when you perform the following operations:
>
> - Create a database.
> - Add data or log files, to an existing database.
> - Increase the size of an existing file (including autogrow operations).
> - Restore a database or filegroup.
>
> In SQL Server, for data files only, instant file initialization (IFI) allows for faster execution of the previously mentioned file operations, since it reclaims used disk space without filling that space with zeros. Instead, disk content is overwritten as new data is written to the files.

Shrinking should be a rarer or never occuring event. If your database files grew to a specific size, that happened due to a specific reason such as actual data growth or actions that caused the Log files to grow. Unless a major change occurs to your database (e.g. historical data retention is cut in half, or the root processes that are causing the file growth are stopped) then there's no point in Shrinking, as the database is just going to grow to that size again.

Also be aware that Shrinking fragments your indexes.